# Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503 after installing Cilium on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, cilium

I'm new to Kubernetes world .Followed InstallKubernetesI have installed Kubernetes cluster with 1 master node and 2 worker nodes.I used kubeadm to install on master node on my local machine.After installing CILIUMQuickInstallation,my coredns pod is Running but not ready

```
[root@master-node ~]# kubectl describe pod coredns-64897985d-cfpvn -n kube-system
Name:                 coredns-64897985d-cfpvn
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000000000
Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Node:                 node-2/10.193.160.170
Start Time:           Tue, 15 Feb 2022 08:12:33 -0500
Labels:               k8s-app=kube-dns
                      pod-template-hash=64897985d
Annotations:          <none>
Status:               Running
IP:                   10.0.1.95
IPs:
  IP:           10.0.1.95
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/coredns-64897985d
Containers:
  coredns:
    Container ID:  docker://2283b42b559c95513f3bfd8c90491b3c8acc55b5542a88d22d2fceaa8c347f9a
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/coredns/coredns:v1.8.6
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/coredns/coredns@sha256:5b6ec0d6de9baaf3e92d0f66cd96a25b9edbce8716f5f15dcd1a616b3abd590e
    Ports:         53/UDP, 53/TCP, 9153/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/UDP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -conf
      /etc/coredns/Corefile
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 15 Feb 2022 08:12:35 -0500
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      memory:  170Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     70Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Readiness:    http-get http://:8181/ready delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/coredns from config-volume (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-b64rl (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      coredns
    Optional:  false
  kube-api-access-b64rl:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:                 CriticalAddonsOnly op=Exists
                             node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule
                             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  2m1s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/coredns-64897985d-cfpvn to node-2
  Normal   Pulled     119s                kubelet            Container image "k8s.gcr.io/coredns/coredns:v1.8.6" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    119s                kubelet            Created container coredns
  Normal   Started    119s                kubelet            Started container coredns
  Warning  Unhealthy  1s (x15 over 119s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
```

Logs of the POD

```
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 62173616170875592.2350229940780337967. HINFO: read udp 10.0.1.95:45853->10.192.0.250:53: read: no route to host
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 62173616170875592.2350229940780337967. HINFO: read udp 10.0.1.95:44728->10.192.0.250:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 62173616170875592.2350229940780337967. HINFO: read udp 10.0.1.95:45554->10.193.0.250:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 62173616170875592.2350229940780337967. HINFO: read udp 10.0.1.95:57310->10.193.0.250:53: i/o timeout
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 62173616170875592.2350229940780337967. HINFO: read udp 10.0.1.95:47540->10.193.0.250:53: i/o timeout
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
```